# Пошаговый перебор массива в обе стороны по клику javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Нуждаюсь в помощи по следующему вопросу:
Мне было необходимо написать скрипт который при вводе css селектора применяет к нему соответствующий css стиль, и если под селектор попадает несколько элементов, то стиль применяется к первому, и с помощью навигационных кнопок можно перемещаться по элементам в перед и назад.

Код с ввода и навигационных кнопок:

```
<input class="selector" type="text"  id="find_btn"/>
<hr/>
<button class="selector-find" onclick="find_selector()">Найти</button>
<button id="selector-next" class="selector-next" onclick="next_selector()" disabled="disabled">Следующий</button>
<button id="selector-prev" class="selector-prev" onclick="prev_selector()" disabled="disabled">Предыдущий</button>
```

Скрипт я написал следующий, но в конце столкнулся с проблемой, по которой прошу помощи, не понимаю как написать функции навигации по списку элементов, верней так как я понимаю, не работает.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // функция которая активирует навигационные кнопки если по селектору больше одногоэлемента
        function SetButtonStatus() {
            document.getElementById("selector-next").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("selector-prev").disabled = false;
        };


        // функция поиска селектора
        function find_selector() {

            // переменные глобальны для доступа к ним из других функцию
            window.str = document.getElementById("find_btn").value;
            window.elems = document.querySelectorAll(str);

            // переводим nodelist в массив
            elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems);

            // проверяем количество полученых элементов по селектору
            window.i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                if (elems.length > 1) {
                    SetButtonStatus();
                }

                // применяем к первому изних нужный css стиль
                if (elems[i].matches(str)) {
                  elems[i].classList.add("marker");
                  break;
                }
            }
        };                        

        // функция которая убирает стиль с текущего элемента и применяет к следующуму подходящему под селектор
        function next_selector() {
            for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].classList.remove("marker");
                elems[i+1].classList.add("marker");
                break;
            }
        };

        // функция которая убирает стиль с текущего элемента и применяет к     предыдущему подходящему под селектор
        function prev_selector() {
            for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i--) {
                elems[i].classList.remove("marker");
                elems[i].classList.add("marker");
                break;
            }
        };

</script>
```

Буду признателен за подсказку в чем у меня ошибка. Спасибо.

Comment: просто храни текущее положение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой задачи удобно использовать двунаправленные списки. [пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpLmomtj/4/)

```
    var input = document.querySelector('.selector'),
    next_btn = document.querySelector('#selector-next'),
    prev_btn = document.querySelector('#selector-prev'),
    active_node;

function node(element, prev, next) {
    this.element = element;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next
}

function find_selector() {
    var selector = input.value;
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if(elements.length) {
        var nodes = Array.from(elements).reduceRight((prev, curr) => {
            curr = new node(curr, null, prev);
            prev && (prev.prev = curr);
            return curr
        }, null);
        set_active_node(nodes)
    } else {
        alert('no elements match given selector')
    }
}

function set_active_node(node) {
    if(active_node) {
        remove_styles(active_node)
    }
    active_node = node;
    apply_styles(active_node)
    toggle_navigation_btns(active_node)
}

function toggle_navigation_btns(node) {
    toggle_disabled(next_btn, !node.next);
    toggle_disabled(prev_btn, !node.prev)
}

function toggle_disabled(btn, is_disabled) {
    btn.disabled = !!is_disabled
}

function remove_styles(node) {
    node.element.classList.remove('active')
}

function apply_styles(node) {
    node.element.classList.add('active')
}

function next_selector() {
    set_active_node(active_node.next)
}

function prev_selector() {
    set_active_node(active_node.prev)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .newstyle {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="selector">1</div>
<div class="selector">2</div>
<div class="selector">3</div>
<div class="selector">4</div>
<div class="selector">5</div>
<div class="selector">6</div>
<div class="selector">7</div>
<div class="selector">8</div>
<div class="selector">9</div>
<div class="selector">10</div>

<button class="up" onclick="up()" disabled>up</button>
<button class="down" onclick="down()" disabled>down</button>
<button onclick="findSelector(selector)">find</button>
</body>
<footer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var buttonUp = document.querySelector('.up');
        var buttonDown = document.querySelector('.down');
        var selector = '.selector'; //your selector.
        var array;
        var index = 0;
        function findSelector(selector){

//disable buttons and remove classes to prevent bugs********************
            buttonDown.disabled = true;
            buttonUp.disabled = true;
            if(!!array){
                for (var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
                    array[i].classList.remove('newstyle');
                }
            }

//***************************************************
            array = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            if(array.length){ //zero length check.
                array[0].classList.add('newstyle');
                index = 0;
                if(array.length != 1){//next element check
                    buttonDown.disabled = false;
                }
            } else alert('selector not found');
        };

        function down(){
            array[index].classList.remove('newstyle');
            index++;
            array[index].classList.add('newstyle');
            buttonUp.disabled = false;
            if (index==array.length-1){
                buttonDown.disabled = true;
            }
        };

        function up(){
            array[index].classList.remove('newstyle');
            index--;
            array[index].classList.add('newstyle');
            buttonDown.disabled = false;
            if (index==0){
                buttonUp.disabled = true;
            }
        };
    </script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Это рабочий вариант вашей задачи. Ну если я правильно понял вашу задачу.